# Separating stacked time series in Excel file into Python upload

Tags: microsoft-excel, python

I have downloaded time series price data, but the data has 4 effective columns (not exactly, but it's all that is pertinent for this question):

date, contract, open price, close price.

The issue is how do I slice each open and close price by contract, and separate them into their own columns so that 'contract1_open_price', etc. is its own column, with one date column for all series.

Otherwise, I could rearrange the series in the source `.csv` file, but that would be less preferable.

See the below screenshot:

[image: data_screenshot]

I would like to have a separate column for each contract e.g. 'Sanders', 'Booker', etc. for each price period.

Thanks, I hope that is clear.

Comment: Hi Sam, A bit of sample data would probably make it lot easier to answer. Just a couple lines of the source in a screen cap would give a bitter idea of what want accomplish.

Comment: If there's a delimiter separating them, you can just do Text To Columns in Excel, no? What have you tried?

Comment: @BradR I have added a screenshot. I hope that helps.@BruceWayne the delimiter is not the issue, nor is doing it in excel, it is just a question of the most efficient method, which I suspect is in python itself.

Comment: I ended up creating separate dataframes for each contract type using str.contains(contractname), then merging each dataframe. However, I had to write a line of code for each contract - lmk if there is an easier way to just add new columns for each unique name id without a new line every time.